# Will mysqli connection close function explicitly close statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

Will mysqli connection close function explicitly close statement

Say I have a code like this

```
new mysqli($host , $userName , $password , $database)

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COLUMNS.....) VALUES (......)"); 

// Other processing
```

`$stmt->close();` ***// DO I HAVE TO INVOKE THIS EXPLICITLY?***

`$mysqli->close();` ***// OR WILL THIS CLOSE THE $stmt***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need neither. As long as you don't experience issues - don't do unnecessary work and let php do it for you

Comment: Say I'm throwing custom exception at processing section

Comment: @SLM: so? Do you experience any issues?

Comment: I'm new to PHP can you please explain then at which point I should explicitly handle these connection closing functions. But as for the reference will connection close handle all other child processes such as statement created on top of connection

Comment: @SLM: all resources will be freed automatically after script ends the work. You need to close them only when you experience any issues, like, with performance, or when your script works long time and your database server cannot handle that much amount of connections

Comment: always close opened connection as your work is done with it. there is always a possibility that something bad happens!